# MySQL server is not starting

Tags: mysql

When I do:

`mysql -u root -p` and type `my password` this is what I get:

> ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

So I type this:

`systemctl restart mysql`

and I got following error:

> Job for mysql.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
>   See "systemctl status mysql.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

So I did `journalctl -xe` and got this output:

```
дек 14 22:57:29 kazak systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
дек 14 22:57:29 kazak systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
Defined-By: systemd
Unit mysql.service has failed.
The result is RESULT.
дек 14 22:57:30 kazak systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
дек 14 22:57:30 kazak systemd[1]: mysql.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 14.
Subject: Automatic restarting of a unit has been scheduled
Defined-By: systemd
```

So I did this: `systemctl status mysql.service` And the output is this:

```
mysql.service - MySQL Community Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/mysql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Fri 2018-12-14 22:59:11 +06; 5s ago
  Process: 14585 ExecStartPre=/usr/share/mysql/mysql-systemd-start pre (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 4037 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS); Control PID: 14594 (mysqld)
    Tasks: 14 (limit: 4915)
   CGroup: /system.slice/mysql.service
           ├─14594 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid
           └─14596 /usr/sbin/mysqld --daemonize --pid-file=/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid`
```

Does anyone knows how to fix, please?

Comment: Maybe.. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/131151/cannot-restart-mysql? or https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/208615/what-is-the-hy-number-hy000-in-mysql-error-messages would need to see more detailed logs: DBA site may get you better responses.

Comment: Nope! Those links were not helpful at all! Sorry!

Comment: I solved it by `sudo mysql`, and then `ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password';` and then `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`