# MYSQL - 8.0.13 - Values on VIEW_DEFINITION column, from information_schema.VIEWS, only displayed to view creator

Tags: mysql

I tried to get values for all views created using this sentence:
 `select * from information_schema.views;` 
but, in spite of being root, only views created by the user running previous command, are filled with values in VIEW_DEFINITION column. Rest of columns are complety filled in all cases.

Looking for information I have found this link about a bug: [BUG MYSQL 39733](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=39733).

Not sure if it is the expected behaviour or it is still a bug in this MySQL version (8.0.13)
In MySQL version 5.7.9 it worked fine.

I know there is  a workaround: `show create view testView;` but I'm interesting in first command to avoid modify the code of a program using MySQL 5.7.9.

Answer (score 1):

It is a MySQL version bug I think. Update your mysql.

Comment: Thanks, but 8.0.13 is the last available:   MySQL Community Server (GPL)
(Current Generally Available Release: 8.0.13)

Comment: My suggestion is re-assign the root user by flushing all the privileges. Also check this link ```https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53784296/mysql-server-is-not-starting?noredirect=1#comment94420587_53784296```

Comment: i like your idea because only one user is using that feature. This workaround will work until a new MySQL version will be delivered without this bug. Thanks!